# WebApp Content-Length Response Header

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS web app responses use chunked encoding (they seem to set the header Transfer-Encoding →chunked). But in my case I would need the Content-Length header instead.

I know that from GAS we cannot change or set response headers, but anyone knows if through some setting, content type or deployment change this can be affected to use Content-Length header?

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What I describe is not specific to my code. Google App Scripts web apps create responses using chunked encoding. Im asking if there is any way to change that, but its a broader question that my particular code.

Comment: I've remove all tags related to generic web apps to prevent confusions, this is a topic related to Google App Scritps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. This cannot be done at the moment, there are no options on Google Apps Scripts to affect this output.